# ReactJs how can I fix missing semicolon error at "render()"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know where I missed the semi-colon. bellow is the error code.

> Syntax error: Missing semicolon. (106:11)

```
  104 |   }
  105 |
  106 |   render() {
      |           ^
  107 |     return (
  108 |       <div className="App">
  109 |         <ParticlesBg type="circle" bg={true} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the code in line 106.

One of the following could be the reason for your error,

1. **Unescaped strings** : This error can occur easily when not escaping strings properly and the JavaScript engine is expecting the end of your string already.
   E.g:

   var foo = 'Tom's bar';
   // SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Could be corrected as,

```
var foo = "Tom's bar";
```

2. **Declaring properties with var** : You cannot declare properties of an object or array with a var declaration.

   var obj = {};
   var obj.foo = 'hi'; // SyntaxError missing ; before statement

   var array = [];
   var array[0] = 'there'; // SyntaxError missing ; before statement

Could be corrected as,

```
var obj = {};
obj.foo = 'hi';

var array = [];
array[0] = 'there';
```

You can check out more about it from here : [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Missing_semicolon_before_statement)